Why session is undefined when I retrieve it in client side with useSession hook?
So this is my /login page.tsx page
"use client";
import React, { FormEvent, useEffect } from "react";
import { signIn, useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

const page = () => {

  const {data: session, status} = useSession();
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {

    console.log(session);

    if (status === 'authenticated') {
      router.push('/')
    }
    
    
  },[])
  

  async function loggUser(e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const form = new FormData(e.currentTarget);

    const email = form.get("email");
    const password = form.get("password");

    const data = {
      email: email,
      password: password,
    };

    signIn('credentials',{...data, redirect: true, callbackUrl:"/"}).then((callback) => {

      if(callback?.error){
        alert(callback.error)
      }

      if(callback?.ok){

        //router.push("/");
        alert("User logged in successful");
      }
    })

  }

  return (
    <div className="flex min-h-full flex-1 flex-col justify-center px-6 py-12 lg:px-8">
      <div className="sm:mx-auto sm:w-full sm:max-w-sm">
        <img
          alt="Your Company"
          src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/mark.svg?color=indigo&shade=600"
          className="mx-auto h-10 w-auto"
        />
        <h2 className="mt-10 text-center text-2xl font-bold leading-9 tracking-tight text-gray-900">
          Sign in to your account
        </h2>
      </div>

      <div className="mt-10 sm:mx-auto sm:w-full sm:max-w-sm">
        <form onSubmit={loggUser} className="space-y-6">
          <div>
            <label
              htmlFor="email"
              className="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900"
            >
              Email address
            </label>
            <div className="mt-2">
              <input
                id="email"
                name="email"
                type="email"
                required
                autoComplete="email"
                className="block w-full rounded-md border-0 py-1.5 text-gray-900 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 placeholder:text-gray-400 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-600 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div>
            <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
              <label
                htmlFor="password"
                className="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900"
              >
                Password
              </label>
              <div className="text-sm">
                <a
                  href="#"
                  className="font-semibold text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500"
                >
                  Forgot password?
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="mt-2">
              <input
                id="password"
                name="password"
                type="password"
                required
                autoComplete="current-password"
                className="block w-full rounded-md border-0 py-1.5 text-gray-900 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 placeholder:text-gray-400 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-600 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div>
            <button
              type="submit"
              className="flex w-full justify-center rounded-md bg-indigo-600 px-3 py-1.5 text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-indigo-500 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-indigo-600"
            >
              Sign in
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>

        <div className="w-full min-h-9 mt-10 relative">
          <div className="absolute top-[50%] w-full h-[1px] bg-slate-300 "></div>
          <div className="bg-white flex justify-center items-center py-3 px-5 absolute top-[50%] left-[50%] translate-x-[-50%] translate-y-[-50%]">
            <p>Or continue with</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="w-full flex justify-center items-center mt-5">
          <button onClick={async () => await signIn('google',{redirect: true, callbackUrl:"/"})}>
            <div className="flex justify-center items-center gap-3 border-slate-200 border-[1px] px-16 py-1 rounded-lg">
              <img
                className="w-8 h-8"
                src="https://cdn-icons-png.freepik.com/256/13170/13170545.png?semt=ais_hybrid"
                alt="Google"
              />
              <p>Google</p>
            </div>
          </button>
        </div>

        <p className="mt-10 text-center text-sm text-gray-500">
          Not a member?{" "}
          <a
            href="#"
            className="font-semibold leading-6 text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500"
          >
            Start a 14 day free trial
          </a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default page;

My idea is to protect my pages - when the user is logged in if try to reach the login page it should be redirected to the home page. But when I console log the session it is undefined. I also have client component
"use client";
import React from "react";

import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";

const UserSession = () => {
  const { data: session,status } = useSession();

  console.log(status);
  

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{session == null ? "not logged in" : "logged in"}</p>
      <p>{JSON.stringify(session)} --- {status}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserSession;

This component is called in /app page.tsx and there is no problem - the session is retrieved. So, any suggestion where could be the problem and is that the right way to protect my pages. Thanks.

If you want to prevent authenticated users from accessing the Log In page, what you're trying to do is unnecessary. Instead, intercept the requests in the middleware and take action accordingly.
middleware.ts
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server"
import { auth } from "auth"

export default auth((request: NextRequest) => {
    // @ts-ignore
    const { auth } = request
    const { pathname } = request.nextUrl

    const searchTerm = request.nextUrl.pathname.split("/").slice(0, 2).join("/")

    if (pathname.startsWith("/login")) {
        const isLoggedIn = !!auth

        if (isLoggedIn) {
            // redirect authenticated users to the Home page if they try to access the Log In page
            return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/home", request.nextUrl))
        }
    }
})

export const config = {
    matcher: ["/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)"],
}

